# Guidelines for logos using multiple typefaces

Tags: fonts, logo, typefaces

I was wondering there were any helpful guidelines and/or tips for designing logos with multiple fonts. It seems to be a dangerous area to enter into, but can lead to some great results.

Often times fonts blend *too* much, or they are *too* different.

Here is an example of a multi-font logo:

[image]

Comment: Olé? That's some bad proofreading. ;)

Comment: It was supposed to be "Huzzah!" but they thought it was too Olde Tyme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been wondering this myself. I'm afraid I can't give any revolutionary, cut and dry guidlines, but I'll try my best.

The theme of your logo is really important in deciding what font(s) you want to use. If it's a more futuristic logo, you'd want to stick with sci-fi fonts. If it's a grunge logo, you want to stick with grunge fonts. Even so, there are som pretty neutral fonts like Arial, Sans, etc.

The size of the text also plays an important role. Complicated fonts (like grunge or fancy fonts) either don't look good or are illegible when they are too small so consider the size of the text when you're choosing your font.

Also consider the shape of your font. In the logo you provided, the "SERVICE PACKAGE" fits nicely below the "Good Ole' Days" especially since the tail of the Y comes down just the right amount and the "SERVICE PACKAGE" is in all caps so it fills the height of th line completely. Look through other graphics designer's websites and logos and do some of your own experimentation to get a feel for what layouts work.

In short, the best advice I can give is to try out a bunch of different fonts and font combinations until you find something that you like. It'll take a while, but if you keep mixing and matching, over time you'll get a good idea of what fonts go best with each other. (I hope that wasn't generally unhelpful)

Answer (score 4):

No guidelines other than basic rules of typography, which can always be broken if it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 4):

There is an old rule that goes: "Never use more than two different typefaces"

The logo actually sticks to that rule. It is a decent rule that prevents one from covering their pages with staffage.

There is another rule that says "rules are meant to be broken (but only for a very good reason)"

Answer (score 3):

When designing a logo, or anything for that matter, you should not use more than 2 typefaces. When you do pick the typefaces for your logo you should make sure that they represent the company and the service that they provide. It doesn't make sense to use a typeface that doesn't represent what the company stands for or does.

I feel the best way to use more than one typeface is to have a 2<sup>nd</sup> typeface that is relatively neutral and gains character from the design rather than giving the design character, such as [Helvetica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica). Keep in mind the hierarchy of typography: a neutral typeface can be used for something that is secondary in importance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say sticking to two different fonts is a good rule, and also they should be contrasting fonts. In your example the two fonts are very different and provide nice contrast. A serif and a sans-serif font would accomplish this as well.

Also in your example, you can see that each font serves a different purpose. The script font adds style, and the simpler font clearly conveys information.