# is it okay to mix two font styles on the front page of a web site?

Tags: website-design, fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts

I am developing a static website which has to look professional.

I found a font (Quicksand) that looks good as a short introductory kind of message / slogan that goes just under the header on the front page.

For the rest of the front page where I detail the services provided and all that jazz, I'd rather use some other less fancy sans like helvetica or verdana. Is it ever okay, from a web design standpoint, to mix two fonts or does it look amateurish?

Otherwise, if I consider using it in the whole site, do you think Quicksand looks good and is legible enough for walls of text with several paragraphs?

Comment: Quicksand is good for titles and slogans. Don't use it for articles, since users' eyes aren't accustomed to such geometric fonts. You could use such font to write a children's book with four big sentences at each page, but not when publishing an academic paper. Mixing fonts is very common, especially serif fonts with sans-serif fonts. You want to alternate the font you're using and the degree in which you're using a certain type of font to for make things stand out. If you want to go into detail then get some books on typography.

Comment: Yes, it i OK to use different font styles.

Comment: See these related posts: [Considerations when using multiple font faces](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13770/23061) and [When are typefaces considered conflicting with each other?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/62880/23061)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable to use two fonts on a site, especially when your plan is to use one of the fonts as a heading. I wouldn't use the font Quicksand (or really any font that I'd use as a title), as the font for paragraphs. Often they lack legibility and/or just don't look right.

So there's no problem generally with using two fonts on a website, but after two, I'd really start to weigh up the pros and cons of using multiple. Using too many can start to clutter the page and ruin any typographic hierarchy ([see here](http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fyti/typographic-tips/typographic-hierarchy)) you have have begun to establish.

Have fun :)

Comment: Another issue to watch out for would be the performance hit for the browsers requesting font files. More fonts, more of a performance hit. Slow page loads will drive away users faster than anything.